# Django 1.5 Class Based Views with custom validation messages from the model

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-1.5

I'm writing a fairly simple bit of CRUD in my django application for project management. I've got the following set up (leaving out the various imports etc for brevity):

```
#models.py:
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250, error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a name for your project.'})
    description = models.TextField()

#views.py
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project

#templates/projects/project_form.html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I visit my update page, the form is displayed with my two fields (name and description). If I leave out the name then submitting the form brings back an error of

```
This field is required
```

rather than

```
Please enter a name for your project.
```

Can I get my custom error message as defined in the model to display instead of the generic "This field is required"?

Comment: you can define clean method in modelform

Comment: best practice is to use a modelform and set the *errors* property of the according field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Django ticket regarding the issue you're having: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13693

Looks like it's been accepted but hasn't been fixed yet. Your best bet for now is to explicitly handle the validation in your form class.